# SSAS: How to model KPI goals for different levels on hierarchy

Tags: ssas, data-modeling, business-intelligence, olap-cube

I have a simple SSAS model from a fact table FactPerformance:
- DateKey
- WorkplaceKey
- Measure1
- Measure2

The dimension DimWorkplace consists of a hierachy:
Plant
 Department
  Area
   Workplace

I have to create KPIs where the goals are given by Area and Department. The goals for the Workplace has to be calculated from the Area where it is assigned to. The goals are not aggregateable and have to be configurable in a way like:
Plant = "Plant 1", Department = "Milling": Goal1 = 0.82, Goal3 = 0.85
Plant = "Plant 1", Department = "Milling", Area = "Area A": Goal1 = 0.9, Goal2 = 0.92

Furthermore, the goals might change over time, the values have to be historized (SCD?).

My first idea was to turn the dimension DimWorkplace into a SCD and add the attributes for the goals. For various reasons I would prefer an independet storage for the goals.

I had troubles finding examples for some sample implementations. Are there any best practices? How are those challenges usually solved? Do you have any hints for me? Thanks in advance!

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add another fact table "FactPerformanceGoal" with the same dimensions and measures.

Another (prefered) is to add a dimension called "Version" to your fact tabe. The "version" dimension has 2 members. "actual" and "goal". Link all your current rows in the fact to "actual" and then add more rows linked to "goal" for your goals. 
Ssas supports a default member for dimensions. Make the "actual" member the default member and set the dimension to "not aggregateable".